# Problem with the while loop in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I was trying to execute a script in which the sed command will remove the first record and will pass the remaining records to the data file but the data file is again getting the first line which got removed by the sed command.

```
while :
do
    head -1 $dataFile > $tempfile
    err_count=0
    if [ $err_count -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Error count is not zero"
    fi
    sed '1d' $dataFile
done
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You never change `err_count` at all, you never use `tempfile` at all, you always completely rewrite `tempfile` every time through the loop, and when you run the final `sed`, you don't direct the output anywhere in particular. And because you're in an endless loop, this code is going to be burning CPU as fast as it can for no obvious reason.

Comment: ...there are enough things wrong here that it's impossible to say which _specific_ thing that's wrong is the one you want our help with.

Comment: Could you try to write a [mre], complete with sample data, expected output, and actual output (as generated by running the code in your question as-is without any changes)?

Comment: (if the problem is that you expect `sed '1d' "$dataFile"` to _modify_ `dataFile`... well, it doesn't do that and isn't supposed to in the first place; `sed` only modifies its input files when given the nonstandard `-i` argument, but that's not safe behavior to rely on when something else is running at the same time as your program: you can easily get into a race condition when `sed`'s writes overwrite a change whatever else was writing to `dataFile` at the same time was supposed to make, causing that other change to get lost).

Comment: ...if your real goal is to build something like a job queue, a text file with one job per line is not a good way to do it: UNIX filesystem semantics aren't optimized for being able to remove a single line off the top of a file; it's an operation that gets slower the longer your file is, because everything after the point you're removing needs to be rewritten from the beginning. There are tools much better suited to the job -- often, one might choose a daemon like [redis](https://redis.io).

Comment: But even if you don't want to use any dedicated servers, a directory with a separate file per job is much less trouble to handle efficiently and correctly than a text file with a line per job. A filesystem with indexed directories (which is a widely available feature these days) can do a lookup, or a deletion, or a creation all in amortized constant time, _much_ better than needing to do a `O(n)` rewrite for every deletion, as is the case with your `sed 1d` approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for all your inputs, I am really new to this bash scripting, I'll analyze the script again